# Why does my <div> not detect my <p> as part of it?

Tags: html

I put a `<div>` tag and inside of it I put an image, h3, and p, but for some reason, the div only detects the image and h3 inside of it (I tried to add a background-color to the div, and that helped show that my `<p>` is outside the div)

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="middlesection">
    <p id="perfect"> THE PERFECT ICE CREAM FOR EVERY OCCASION</p>  

    <div id="product1">
        <img id="firsticecream" src="/Users/andygiovannyfebrianto/Desktop/First Page/images/product/1.png">
        <h3 class="learn-more">Learn More ></h3>
        <p class="textdesc">Mint ice cream on top of strawberry <br> Perfect for a hot day!</p>
    </div>

    <div id="product2">
        <img id="secondicecream" src="/Users/andygiovannyfebrianto/Desktop/First Page/images/product/2.png">
        <h3 class="learn-more">Learn More ></h3>
        <p class="textdesc">Strawberry ice cream with a whip of cream <br> Perfect balance!</p>
    </div> 

    <div id="product3">
        <img id="thirdicecream" src="/Users/andygiovannyfebrianto/Desktop/First Page/images/product/3.png">
        <h3 class="learn-more">Learn More ></h3>
        <p class="textdesc">Strawberry ice cream on a stick<br> So refreshing!</p>
    </div>              
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'detect my <p>'?

Comment: You should close img and br tags but that doesn't generate the issue... you have this live anywhere? It appears fine at first glance.

Comment: Can you show your css for div and p. Can you explain "div is not detecting p" clearly?

Comment: @zozo: They don't have to be closed. This is not XHTML.

Comment: @BoltClock I said should not must :). Also pointed out that's not the issue.

Comment: @zozo: So why *should* they be closed? Just because that's your preferred style?

Comment: Because using strict version of coding and coding according to strict standards ensures readability at once, compatibility with imperfect implementations of browsers. That question is from the same category as "why indent code in html?" or "why use doctype"? You don't have to do it. No1 will say anything if you don't. But the guy is LEARNING. Maybe you should learn the strict version instead of the quirky one????

Comment: @zozo strict and quirk and transitional are forms of XHTML, not HTML. Two different things.

Comment: @TylerH - actually you couldn't be more wrong. Strict and transitional are forms of both HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.0, and HTML5 in neither the HTML or XHTML syntaxes has that distinction. Furthermore, quirks mode is a browser mode that can only be accessed with the HTML mime type. True XHTML *always* uses standards mode.

Comment: @zozo - There's nothing at all "strict" about putting a slash before the angle bracket to complete a void element tag. The element is properly closed without it in HTML. It's just permitted for those who prefer it as syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Alohci Sorry, I was referring to HTML5 only when I said HTML; I'm assuming no one here (hopefully anywhere) is bothering with HTML 4.01 anymore.

Comment: @TylerH - OK, but be aware that HTML5 comes in XHTML form too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually missing a div on top of first `<p id="perfect"> THE PERFECT ICE CREAM FOR EVERY OCCASION</p>`

Try below:

```css
div {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <p id="perfect"> THE PERFECT ICE CREAM FOR EVERY OCCASION</p>  

    <div id="product1">
        <img id="firsticecream" src="/Users/andygiovannyfebrianto/Desktop/First Page/images/product/1.png">
        <h3 class="learn-more">Learn More ></h3>
        <p class="textdesc">Mint ice cream on top of strawberry <br> Perfect for a hot day!</p>
    </div>

    <div id="product2">
        <img id="secondicecream" src="/Users/andygiovannyfebrianto/Desktop/First Page/images/product/2.png">
        <h3 class="learn-more">Learn More ></h3>
        <p class="textdesc">Strawberry ice cream with a whip of cream <br> Perfect balance!</p>
    </div> 

    <div id="product3">
        <img id="thirdicecream" src="/Users/andygiovannyfebrianto/Desktop/First Page/images/product/3.png">
        <h3 class="learn-more">Learn More ></h3>
        <p class="textdesc">Strawberry ice cream on a stick<br> So refreshing!</p>
    </div>              
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it and it is still there, let me add more detail to the question. Thanks

Comment: I think something in my upper part of the is missing, anyway i add the div like you said and it is fixed now, Thanks!

Comment: @AndyGiovannyFebrianto If the answer helped you fixed your issue you should accept it.

Comment: Oh sorry, first time i use stack overflow. My bad

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you don't use HTML entities. Try to close img and br tags and replace '>' character with HTML entity. Just try this HTML code.

```
<div>
    <p id="perfect"> THE PERFECT ICE CREAM FOR EVERY OCCASION</p>
    <div id="product1">
        <img id="firsticecream" src="/Users/andygiovannyfebrianto/Desktop/First Page/images/product/1.png"/>
        <h3 class="learn-more">Learn More &gt;</h3>
        <p class="textdesc">Mint ice cream on top of strawberry <br/> Perfect for a hot day!</p>
    </div>

    <div id="product2">
        <img id="secondicecream" src="/Users/andygiovannyfebrianto/Desktop/First Page/images/product/2.png"/>
        <h3 class="learn-more">Learn More &gt;</h3>
        <p class="textdesc">Strawberry ice cream with a whip of cream <br/> Perfect balance!</p>
    </div>

    <div id="product3">
        <img id="thirdicecream" src="/Users/andygiovannyfebrianto/Desktop/First Page/images/product/3.png"/>
        <h3 class="learn-more">Learn More &gt;</h3>
        <p class="textdesc">Strawberry ice cream on a stick<br/> So refreshing!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Like I said above, this is not XHTML, or at least I wouldn't assume the asker is writing XHTML. The img and br tags don't need to be closed. And the loose > signs are valid and not causing any problems.